# Track version history of CV edits

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think it would be really great if Careers was able to track the history of your edits to your CV over time, like any version control system would do.

I'm sure it isn't easy to implement on the backend but I think it'd be a really great nice-to-have for the technical audience.

Answer (score 1):

To what end would this feature be implemented? What problem would it solve?

Comment: Allow quick recovery from a bad session of "drunk resume padding"...
("chief pony groomer at-" WHERE DID *THAT* COME FROM?!)

Comment: Yeah, basically for undo and "oops I screwed up" ability